# Create csv from db data in django project

Tags: html, django, csv

I have one django project and want to create one csv file from the data in html(xxx) table by clicking the button in html template. What should the code be look like to fulfill such function? Here's the view.py, Model and html template of my project. Really thanks!

Html:
Html(xxx):

```
<table>
      <tr>
          <th><div class="panel-heading">No.</div></th>
          <th><div class="panel-heading">Search Content</div></th>
          <th><div class="panel-heading">Title</div></th>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          {% for i in datas %}
           <td><div class="panel-body"><small>{{forloop.counter}}</div></td>
           <td><div class="panel-body">{{ i.0 }}</div></td>
           <td><div class="panel-body">{ i.1 }}</div></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

view.py:

```
def table(request):
    user = request.user
    data = Outputting.objects.filter.order_by('batch_id').values_list('col_a1', 'col_b1')
    return render(request, "xxx.html", {"datas": data})
```

Model:

```
class Outputting(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    batch_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    col_a1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    col_b1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

After click the button, csv could be generated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the official Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/outputting-csv/).

As you can see from the code snippet below (taken from the aforementioned link), you can implement a simple view to export the table to a csv within a new view.

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
    writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])

    return response
```